# What is the exact type of oil used in immersion cooling of electronic devices such as processors?

Tags: cooling, processor

I am looking for cooling solutions for a data center with low PUE. I can see that there is an immersion cooling option which uses a very specific oil based liquid that is non conductive but can observe heat efficiently.

I wanna buy this oil from local market but don't know what exactly I should ask for. What is the scientific name of this type of oil? I found "3M Novec Engineered fluid" online, but there is not much details about what type of oil it is and I can not find it in my country (Thailand).

Can I use cooking oil? or something similar?

Comment: What do you want to know beyond the datasheets: http://multimedia.3m.com/mws/media/65495O/3mtm-thermal-management-fluids.pdf?fn=bro_heattrans.pdf     and... http://multimedia.3m.com/mws/media/199818O/3mtm-novectm-7100-engineered-fluid.pdf    I can't imagine any type of oil would be satisfactory since the phase change temperature would be hundreds deg C and you'd have to use conductive heat transfer!! Whereas the 3M 7100/7200 phase change is 61/76 deg C.

Comment: Thanks @JackCreasey, then I just have to find a way to buy this 3M liquid from somewhere in the world and post it to Thailand.

Comment: I don't think oil-cooled computers use phase change. Heat is conducted to the oil and then convection transports the heat within the oil bath. Heat pipes use phase change. Heat pipes are common in computers, and I prefer them over oil cooling.

Comment: Some of the early cray computers didn't use oil at all, they used Fluorinert (possibly because when pulled apart, it all eventually boils off leaving clean circuit boards)

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK people usually use mineral oil. For example:

http://www.instructables.com/id/Mineral-Oil-Submerged-PC/

See also:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformer_oil

Comment: "Transformer oil" and "mineral oil" were two good search keywords. thanks.